# How can I pass parameters using ObjectDataSource?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm new to ASP.NET and I need some help.

I've got a function which gets two parameters and returns an object:

```
Calculate(Persondata as Persondata,Tables as Tables) as object(,)
```

How can I pass the parameters and view this object using `ObjectDataSource`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete guide for passing parameters to ObjectDataSource control.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57hkzhy5.aspx